# Member data overwritten on stack instance

Tags: c++

Useless background: I'm on my Nth iteration of working on setting up an entity/component based game engine. I have enough code written now such that I can start testing some of the function calls. The odd behavior I'm seeing is that instance members are being set to different values than I expect, yet they're always the same from run to run. At one point the code example below resulted in two consecutive integers being displayed, but now two non-consecutive integers are being displayed and I'm not sure why.

Problem: I'm developing an entity system that relies on handles so I can keep homogeneous data collected in memory to avoid cache misses (read: contained as copies in vectors). However, for two consecutively created entities I'm getting drastically different handle values back when they should be consecutive. The code that is testing this behavior is:

```
#include <dbes/engine.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Engine engine(10000);

    Handle e1 = engine.createEntity();
    Handle e2 = engine.createEntity();

    std::cout << "e1: " << (unsigned int)e1 << " e2: " << (unsigned int)e2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The library code is available [here](https://github.com/TheBurrito/dbes).

The output is :

```
e1: 50331648 e2: 33564418
```

When I step through the call, the members of the `m_handleManager` instance within the `Engine` instance on the second call to `createEntity()` seems to have all changed. When I debug in eclipse the values are as follows: (They are all their expected, initialized values on the first call)

```
m_maxEntries : 4294959264
m_activeCount: 32767
m_firstFreeIndex: 9986
```

It is of note that the return from the first call to `createEntity()` always steps me through the d'tor of vector. I'm sure this has to do with my problem but I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Nobody is going to download all your code and debug it for you.  Sorry.

Comment: Especially not when *you* modified the code you downloaded. The source on GitHib has the constructor for `Engine(unsigned int maxHandles);` as private. So `Engine engine(10000);` shouldn't even *compile*. There is supposed to be only a singleton managed by the static members of the class.

Comment: Well thank you for pointing out my stupidity. However, _I_ had not modified the code. [Building with code provided exactly as in post](http://imgur.com/OO7JtN5)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I didn't expect them to. I was suspecting it would be readily apparent to someone perusing the code, as WhozCraig demonstrated.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Bare links are frowned upon?

Comment: @TheBurrito I wouldn't say frowned upon... they're just a little ugly to look at.

Answer (score 0):

As WhozCraig pointed out, I had my Engine class set up as a singleton. Somehow g++ / eclipse were masking the problem and resulting in a compile even though I was using a c'tor for Engine instead of my static init and instance functions. I had switched back and forth a few times on whether I was going to have Engine be a singleton and without the compiler yelling at me I had forgot to keep my test code updated.

Edit:
I played around adding c'tors and got the compiler to complain. I then removed them again and the compiler still complained. I'm not sure who's at fault here; whether it's make, gcc, or eclipse but somehow building succeed, with obviously unexpected results.

I'll edit this again if I can reproduce the compilation again and find out where the disconnect was.